# Insert icon in Shopify menu using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, icons, shopify

I'm trying to add icon in my Shopify menu like this :

[The menu I want with icons before titles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtFBA.png)

The only way I found for adding icon to Shopify header menu is to use Jquery.
So I added Jquery script to my `theme.liquid` and I've followed the steps in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TSz6T_aMo4)  but the script won't work.

Here's the script :

```
<script>
  $('#HeaderMenu-fleurz').text(function(){
    
  var navText = $(this).text();
    $(this).prepend('<img scr="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0782/7714/9020/files/flower-tulip.png?v=1696549391"/>');
    }
  });
</script>
```

And here's the inspector on the item :

[My Shopify website now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQgJR.png)

Sorry I'm not an English native, and thanks a lot for your help !

I tried some homemade script but I'm not js dev, nor dev at all so nothing would work

Comment: just do it from liquid, header or nav

Comment: there is absolutely no reason to use jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation**

Hi, it'll be good if you could post your html code together, so we can understand your issue better. I guess you are trying to prepend the  element into the menu header

**Code**

```
   <script>
        var imgsrc = $("<img>").attr("src", "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0782/7714/9020/files/flower-tulip.png?v=1696549391")
        $('#HeaderMenu-fleurz').prepend(imgsrc);
   </script>
```

Comment: Hi,
I don't know which HTLM you've needed but your script WORKS ! ✨
That's exactly what I wanted to do !  That's working fine now.
And I guess that if I want to add icon to other menu items I can just change the ID  $('here') ?

You saved me !
If you ever need a graphic designer hmu !

Comment: @AllanKhairi, yes, you could change the id to add icon to other menu items, glad to help you